# Looking for some good RPCs

Tags: rpc

Where can I find good Ethereum RPCs for free? I know there are some public RPCs but I am looking for one without any/less rate limiting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free and public Ethereum JSON-RPC API nodes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102967/free-and-public-ethereum-json-rpc-api-nodes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out QuickNode https://www.quicknode.com/.

- There's a free lifetime plan.
- It's the fastest RPC provider.

It gives you the lowest latency regardless of your location.

Check out this blog post: https://blog.quicknode.com/justifying-quick-in-quicknode-response-time-comparison-of-various-blockchain-node-providers/

Answer (score 0):

Try https://api.securerpc.com/v1 -- We do not store logs for more than 30 days and support all Ethereum DApps.

Manifold Finance (my startup) maintains this RPC and Relay as a public good. If you have any issues feel free to reach out!